# unicode string in c++ with boost

Tags: c++, boost, unicode

I want to use unicode string in c++ with any library which implements a lot of its routine. I want to work with the boost libraries. And I found [locale library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/locale/doc/html/index.html). But I did not find that a lot of people use it, don't they? What can you say from your experience about this library? Are there any other boost libraries which implements unicode string routine?

**UPDATE:**

There is a problem with the use of another libraries in some my modules. I don't want to tie them to a lot of different libraries (boost is ok), but I need a unicode string routine (mb class). Why unicode? Mb in some characters of the strings will appear japanese symbols or from other language. And they must be treated as english characters.

Comment: If you're looking for basic Unicode strings, you probably want [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/). If you're looking for a framework which uses Unicode strings consistently throughout, then go for [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/products/).

Comment: "And I found locale library. But I did not find that a lot of people use it, don't they?" That's not a surprise. It didn't exist in Boost until 1.48, which was only a few months ago. Also, it should be noted that Locale doesn't have "unicode strings". It has tools to *manipulate* unicode-encodings. But it has no string type that specifically enforces the Unicode restrictions.

Comment: Please see my first comment to @vitakot answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please excuse the self promotion here, but you might be interested in the answer I wrote here: [What are the tradeoffs between boost::locale and std::locale?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31860184/what-are-the-tradeoffs-between-boostlocale-and-stdlocale), comparing boost::locale to std::locale.

Depending on what you need to do with your text, boost::locale is probably the best approach to adding unicode support to your c++ code.  This is especially true if you need cross platform support, or you want to use UTF-8 on Windows.